# jQuery getting the row that triggered the event and updating specific td in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, html-table

I'm trying to capture the index of the row that triggered the event in my table which looks like following:

```
<tr>
 <td class="sorting_1" style="text-align:left;" width="10%">
 <a  class="btnWatchList" value="1"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
 <a class="deleteBulkItem" value="2"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I've did something like this:

```
$("#datatable-responsive").delegate("tr", "click", function (e) {
    var index = $(e.currentTarget).index(); // finding the column index

    console.log($(e.currentTarget).index());
    $('#datatable-responsive tr:eq('+index+') td:eq(2)').text('ChangedText'); // changing the text

});
```

So here is the tricky part, I don't want the event to be triggered on just ANY TR CLICK, but rather just a specific button in the TR, which is element:

```
 <a  class="btnEdit" value="1"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
```

And then when I capture the index of the row that triggered the event, then update that row's specific column, whos HTML markup looks like this:

```
 <td class="sorting_1" width="60%">
 <h5 ><b><a href="Title1Link" id="titleText" value="Titl1" id="linkText" target="_blank">Title1</a></b></h5>
 <h6><b><a href="Title2Link" id="" target="_blank">Title2</a></b></h6>
 </td>
```

So now  once I've found the index of the column that triggered the event, I want to set this first a link's text into "Clicked" or something like that, just so I can know it really worked...

So to summarize what I'm trying to achieve here:

- Get row index that triggered the `onclick` event (just on `btnEdit` click, not just any tr click)
- Update first a link's text to "Clicked"

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: $("#datatable-responsive").delegate(".deleteBulkItem)", "click", function (e) { });  change ur selector like this

Comment: *but rather just a specific button in the TR* - Why not bind the click event to the button if you only want to trigger it on that button click?

Comment: @Pete could you show me a quick example on what you ment ?

Comment: @Pete if you mean something like JYoThl posted, I did it like that but I always get index  as value 0 ... ?

Comment: @JYoThI if I do it that way then I always get index = 0 for any clicked row ... ?

Comment: index seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9gd3r90g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target the button and traverse up to row using [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). Based on code shown you don't even seem to need the index, just the row object

```
$("#datatable-responsive").delegate("tr .btnEdit", "click", function (e) {
     var $row = $(this).closest('tr');       
     $row.find('td:eq(2)').text('ChangedText'); // changing the text    
});
```

Note that `delegate()` is deprecated and if you are using jQuery version greater than 1.7 you should be using `on()` instead

Comment: Charlie hey thanks alot for the reply :) ... This way of changing the text isn't what I'm trying to achieve, this way i would actually update the entire column with text: "ChangedText", but I don't want to update the entire cell 2 in this row, but rather just this part inside the td:  <h5 ><b><a href="Title1Link" id="titleText" value="Titl1" id="linkText" target="_blank">Title1</a></b></h5>

Comment: so add selectors you need to the `find()`

Comment: $row.find('td:eq(2)').find('a:eq(0)').text('ChangedText');

Comment: Simpler to do $row.find('td:eq(2) a').text('ChangedText');

Comment: there is two anchor tag . isn't issue ? @charlietfl

Comment: @JYoThI yes  good point, just tried charlie's way, it updates both anchor tags

Comment: Adjust selector accordingly. You really haven't specified exact behavior needed. Adding a class to what you want modified would help

Answer (score 0):

use class name **.deleteBulkItem** to get the clcik event . and then we use closest to find the parent tr .

```
$("#datatable-responsive").delegate(".deleteBulkItem", "click", function (e) { 

var tr = $(this).closest('tr').index();
$('#datatable-responsive tr:eq('+tr+') td:eq(2)').find('a.eq(0)').text('ChangedText');  

//or you traverse like this 

 var  $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.find('td:eq(2)').find('a.eq(0)').text('ChangedText');

});
```

Comment: bad practice using global variable for `tr`

Comment: traverse also given . please check my updated answer @charlietfl